# Selenium WebDriver find_element_by_xpath not working for text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a link on a webpage that has no ID and no individual class. The only thing to lock it down to is the text 'Sessions'.

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sessions')]");

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Sessions']");
```

Both come back with "No such element".

Edit: I have also tried `driver.find_element_by_link_text` which also didn't work.

I've tried using the full xpath:

```
/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/nav/a[3]
```

To no avail.

[image: Here's the HTML, and 'Sessions' is the last link]

Answer (score 0):

That is a `link_Text` cause it's between anchor tag, use this :

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sessions').click()
```

or

A way more good approach is to use `ExplicitWaits` :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Sessions')))
element.click()
```

If you want explicit wait you would need to import the below :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If the above gives you `NoSuchElementException`, I would probably suspect this it is in iframe (See the screenshot first tag - I can see body), if it happens to be then in that case you would need to switch to iframe first and continute with this web element.

**Code**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe xpath here")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Sessions"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I forgot to add I've already tried link_text and this results in the same "No such element" error. Upon trying your other solution, python gives a timeout error. I'll keep trying, thanks again.

Comment: Did you try the second solution ? If that did not work out, what did you pass in place of `iframe xpath here` ?